# AWT font rendering and metrics alternative

Tags: java, fonts

AWT font rendering and metrics seems not suitable for real printing application. Font rendering depends on DPI, FontMetrics gives wrong results. So it is actually impossible to render real text inside a bounding box.

What is an alternative for Java to render real-life fonts, align texts horizontally and vertically, render text exactly inside a bounding box, etc?

We are rendering text on JPEG and PNG both small DPI and 300 DPI. We also use a lot of different fonts.

Comment: A couple of questions: Are you rendering the fonts, etc, **on-screen** or for **printing**? You are using Java, clearly - any other constraints?

Comment: Another couple of questions to help me answer: 1) Is this an application installed on a client desktop/laptop, or is this a server application serving PNGs/JPEGs to the web? 2) Are you generating a lot of JPEGs/PNGs or are they created infrequently? Can you accept a solution that involves Java calling out to the OS or another application?

Comment: This is a server application generating a lot of PNGs (JPEGs). I think we can accept calling OS or another app. It would be nice though if the application remains OS independent.

Answer (score 5):

One approach is to:

- Create a document in a language more suited to text and formatting, then
- 'Print' or rasterize that document using the typical OS application at the desired DPI.

There are a number of formats that are common, text-based and/or have numerous libraries in Java:

- [TeX/LaTeX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX). TeX has a whole StackExchange site devoted to it: https://tex.stackexchange.com/
- PS/PDF - libraries: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118635/what-is-the-best-pdf-open-source-library-for-java
- HTML/CSS (but this may be harder as it's designed for the web, not physical pages)

LaTex has an easily installed binaries for multiple platforms that will rasterize your image, eg:

> $ tex2png --help
>
> ABOUT
>     tex2png - convert (La)TeX to PNG images
>
> USAGE
>     tex2png [options]
>
> A (La)Tex string can be passed either as a command-line parameter or via
>     STDIN. When manually entered via STDIN, use ctrl+d to terminate input.
>
> OPTIONS
>     -b 
>       The background color to pass to dvipng's "--bg" option. It should be given
>       in TeX color \special syntax, e.g. "rgb 0.2 0.2 0.2". "Transparent" and
>       "transparent" are also accepted. See the dvipng help message for more
>       details. Default: 'transparent'
>
> -c 
>       The (La)TeX string.
>
> -d 
>       The output directory. See below.
>
> -f
>       Specify the full input document. By default, tex2png provides its own
>       headers and wraps the input in document tags. This option enables the user
>       to provide a full (La)TeX document with custom headers.
>
> -i
>       Inline mode. This will include the height and depth in the output, which can
>       be used for vertical alignment in web pages, e.g.
>
> -h
>       Display this help message.
>
> -o 
>       The image path. See below.
>
> -p 
>       Page number to render. Default is 1.
>
> -s 
>       The font size argument passed to "dvipng". Default is 1400.
>
> -t 
>       The temporary working directory. A random directory is created with "mktemp"
>       by default.
>
> -T
>       Crop whitespace around the content (dvipng -T tight).
>
> OUTPUT
>     If the image path is set then it is the full path to the image. If it is not
>     set then the image name will be the sha256 digest of the (La)Tex input string
>     with the ".png" extension. If the output directory has been set then the image
>     will be saved there, otherwise it will be saved in the current directory.

For PS/PDF files, you can use the appropriate Adobe application, the OS or ImageMagick ([video here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7xuxsd3I0Q4)):

> $ convert -density 300 file.pdf output.png

Answer (score 1):

Desktop Publishing software often hits the limit of highperformance Systems. To DTP with Java is a bad idea. You will be addicted to fast atomar calculations so different programs written in c/c++ or other low-level programming languages.

Thats why i accept Andrew's answer in the fact that a external program even better.

If you are looking for a Java-Project that something like Desktop publishing you may be happy with using http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-library in example.